# GEO block on AWS WAF but sometimes Country header is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

We're consuming AWS WAF logs into Athena from S3 to facilitate custom queries.

One of the rules I have applied is a geo block on the country level as it's a local service. This morning we had some reports of some user being blocked, from within our country. 
Digging into the waf logs we found that when this occurs the country header is simple a dash.

Any idea how this could happen or how to work around this? we are seeing quite a few of these in the logs.

[image: Country missing]

Comment: DId you ever find a solution to this?